# How to refer to an assembly name of an empty project with neither a string literal nor a dummy type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When working with Entity Framework Core migration, I prefer separating Target project from Startup project.

The Startup project is a Console Application with the following snippet.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Needs a host
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(svc =>
        {
            svc.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlServer(// other parameters go here
                , _ => _.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Dummy))!.GetName().Name));
            });
        })
        .Build();
}
```

And the Target project is a Class Library project with a `Dummy` class as follows.

```
public class Dummy
{
}
```

We can also make the Target project 100% empty but I have to change `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Dummy))!.GetName().Name` to a string literal `"Target"` (assuming the Target project is named `Target`).

## Question

I am curious whether there is another elegant way (with neither dummy class nor string literal) to reference an empty Target project.

[My repo](https://github.com/pstricks-fans/Separated-Projects) maybe useful for testing rather than creating from zero.

Comment: You don't need to register migration assembly as part of Startup project. Consider to use design time context factory instead.

Comment: I am sure that you don't need to create in startup project, but create in target project and execute migration commands against target project

Comment: Are you trying to fight the framework? What is the purpose of separating Startup and Target?

Comment: If you want to keep migrations in different project - run migrations against that project. Reference Db Context in target project and execute migrations there - no need startup at all

Comment: `MigrationAssembly` method takes `string` as an argument - so anyway you end up with the string value. Do you get it from the type or list of loaded assemblies matters only if we know the reason behind not wanting to use type or string filter.

Comment: What is the EF Core feature you are after?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's elegant or bulletproof but you could search through all assemblies (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`) for the one that has a class that derives from `DbMigration` or `DbContext` with the help of [Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-6.0).

Comment: The Target project is an empty class library that references another project containing `DbContext`. There are 4 projects in total. Startup project (for executing `add-migration`) , Target  project (for generated `Migrations` folder), Context project (for db context) and Entity project (for data model).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code:

```
var targetAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
          .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == "Assembly.Name");
```

Comment: `"Assembly.Name"` is a string literal that I want to avoid.

Comment: So let me get this straight... you want to reference an assembly without using a string to identify it and without referencing any class in it?

Comment: Yes. Is it not possible?